# Dask Visualise Color and Optional Arguments (graphviz kwargs)

Tags: python, plot, graph, dask

I don't know how to use the **optional arguments** to graphviz of the `visualise()` method in Dask. Here's the task I'm working with:

```py
import os
from dask import delayed
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'my path to graphviz bin'

def inc(x):
    return x + 1

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

x = delayed(inc)(1)
y = delayed(inc)(2)
z = delayed(add)(x, y)
z.compute()

z.visualize(color='order', cmap='viridis')
```

[image]

I want to change parameters, and the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.visualize) of the `visualise()` call says

> **kwargs
>
> Additional keyword arguments to forward to to_graphviz.

**What are these keyword arguments? How can I use them?**

Answer (score 0):

This function is available at `dask.dot.to_graphviz`

It in turn passes keywords off to the Python `graphviz` library.